# How to generate payu UPI intent loader

Tags: payment, google-pay, payu, upi

I am looking for a solution using PayU to collect payments via GPay intent flow on a mobile web page.

One of the solutions is to open a payu page via a form as displayed on their demo page here: https://www.payubiz.in/upi

However, their page after opening the form, automatically redirects to a url of the form: https://api.payu.in/public/#/77748b2d3e286bf7d82862ab0d0aca19/upi .

This redirection is unclear to me. How is this URL generated? Can I make an api call to PayU to simply generate this URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found one solution.

We need to invoke payu APIs for UPI payments with following parameters alongwith others:

```
{
    bankcode: TEZ,
    pg: UPI,
    txn_s2s_flow: 4
}
```

This request returns a response where one of the fields is acsTemplate which is just an html form encoded in base64. We can open that form directly or extract the value of `action` attribute and open the payu payment page directly that way.